# Risk of removing VirtualHost port 80 in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

Currently my sites in Apache are configured with VirtualHost for ports 80 and 443, my htaccess redirects to https when https is off.

By doing a test removing virtualhost 80 I realized that the browser drops directly to HTTPs.
Is there any risk of removing the setting for port 80 and the site not being accessible in older browsers?

Answer (score 1):

All browsers that never have visited your site will not automatically try https instead of http if you navigate to `http://example.com` and nothing is listening on port 80. If your browser did this is most likely because you have visited the site with https before.

So, don't do this if you want your site to work.

(It might be that newer browsers indeed auto try https in this case, although I've never heard about such a feature without extensions like "HTTPS everywhere" and couldn't find a reference for it. You can't rely on this anyway, as older browsers are still out there in large numbers).

Comment: The HTST pre load list will do that https://opensource.google.com/projects/hstspreload